# .NET MVC 4 Automatic Login after Registration

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

We have a web application using SimpleMembership with a confirmation mail being sent upon registration. Now I want the user to automatically get logged in when he or she verifies the account.

I guess the way to go is to get the user associated with the confirmation token and then use:

```
if (WebSecurity.UserExists(username)) 
{
     FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, false);
}
```

The problem is that there doesn't seem to be any simple way to retrieve the confirmation token. WebSecurity has a function GetUserIdFromPasswordResetToken() but that does not really help.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an article on [retrieving the confirmation token in SimpleMembership](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/04/retrieving-confirmation-token-in.html).

But the intent of retrieving the confirmation token in this article was to resend the email to the user.  I would be careful automatically logging the person in after the confirmation process as it may introduce a security vulnerability.  This would allow anyone that got a hold of the email with the link to log-in to that account.  For security reasons it is best to have the user log-in with their credentials after confirmation. You will see this discussed in the [comments for this article](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/02/adding-email-confirmation-to.html).

Comment: But what if I don't care about the email confirmation? I just want to simply set the user logged in right after he/she successfully submitted the registration form. Even if the email is invalid.

Comment: Using email confirmation is optional and something you add on to the normal code provided by the template.  When you call CreateUserAndAccount just make sure that you set the parameter requireConfirmationToken to false.